# Why is the JDK's BREAKPOINT define given special values on ARM?

Tags: java, jvm, breakpoints

Here is the breakpoint code in jdk.

```
#ifdef ARM
  #ifdef SOLARIS
    #define BREAKPOINT __asm__ volatile (".long 0xe1200070")
  #else
    #define BREAKPOINT __asm__ volatile (".long 0xe7f001f0")
  #endif
#else
  extern "C" void breakpoint();
  #define BREAKPOINT ::breakpoint()
#endif
```

I want to know whether '.long 0xe1200070' and '.long 0xe7f001f0' have special meanings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When porting HotSpot to ARM I've found useful to have a breakpoint inlined rather than call an external `breakpoint()` function. If JVM reaches this place, there will be a meaningful context of the crash: nearby instructions and relevant register values.

`.long 0xe7f001f0` is the encoding for undefined instruction. ARM `0x.7f...f.` instruction space is reserved to generate undefined instruction exception. Obviously there is no mnemonic for it, hence the numeric literal. GDB uses the same opcode for breakpoints on arm-eabi.

`.long 0xe1200070` is the manually encoded `BKPT` opcode. I haven't seen Solaris/ARM platforms, but I guess this is how breakpoints are typically encoded there.